# How to detect a moving object and its position in camera in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, camera

I want to detect movement of an object in iOS camera. Actually I am working on a project where the iOS camera is placed some where and when it detects any movement on the camera screen then it gives notification or fire any particular event.

Please suggest if how can I achieve the same.

Comment: [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) might be of help in your case.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933716/how-can-you-track-motion-using-the-iphones-camera) shall help ! I dont know why StackOverflow doesn't allow me to write less than 30 characters ! :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382780/iphone-camera-how-to-detect-movement-of-object-on-camera-screen


may be helpful

Comment: Can anybody show me some sample by which I can try my motive?